# How to make a Password and User request with a maximum of 4 attempts in Java?

Tags: java, passwords, compare

I am currently stuck in a problem. I am doing a code for a cashier but I am unable to resolve the problematic of the password and user request, it is supposed to have a maximum of 4 attempts before the cashier closes. if anyone could help me resolve this issue i would really appreciate it.

```
public static void login(){
    int TIMESC = 0;
    int TIMESP = 0;
    String PROMT; 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //Keyboard input initializer
    PROMT = ">"; //promt sring definition
    System.out.println("Welcome to LJD Bank");
    System.out.println("Insert Bank account");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf(PROMT);
    CLIENT = keyboard.nextLine(); //to be defined by user
    if(CLIENT.length() != 16){
        if(TIMESC == 0){
            while(TIMESC < 4){
               System.out.println("Not a valid Account");
               System.out.println("Please insert a valid Account");
                System.out.println(PROMT);
               CLIENT = keyboard.nextLine();
               TIMESC ++;
            }
            Cashier.close();
        }    
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Insert NIP");
        System.out.printf(PROMT);
        PASSWORD = keyboard.nextLine();
        if(PASSWORD.length() != 4){ 
            while(TIMESP < 4){
                    System.out.println("Not a valid NIP");
                    System.out.println("Please insert a valid NIP");
                    PASSWORD = keyboard.nextLine();
                    TIMESP ++;
            }
            Cashier.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems you are never comparing the entered password value to the expected one. Also you are allowing 0-length passwords: `CLIENT.length() != 16` which is surely not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to my friend Edvilme who has helped me with the issue. Here is the code:

```
if(CLIENT.length() == 16){ //lenght
            RETRY_CLIENT = 5;//this variable is set to 5 breaking the loop when the client is valid
            while(RETRY_NIP < 4){//while the RETRYNIP is less than four then the nip is requested
                System.out.println("Insert NIP");
                System.out.printf(PROMT);
                PASSWORD = keyboard.nextLine();//NIP is requested
                System.out.println();
                if(PASSWORD.length() == 4){ //if nip length is equal to 4
                    System.out.println("Welcome to your account user " +CLIENT); //gives welcome
                    RETRY_NIP = 5; //entonces se pone como 5 rompiendo el loop
                }
                else if(PASSWORD.length() != 4 && RETRY_NIP == 4){ //if the password length is diferent from 4 and retryNIP is equal to 4 attempts
                    Cashier.close(); //Cashier closes
                }
                else if(PASSWORD.length() != 4){// if the NIP Lenght is diferent from 4 then the NIP is requested again, RETRYNIP increases in 1
                    System.out.println(TRY);
                    RETRY_NIP ++; //RetryNIP is increased in one (+1)
                }
            }
        }
        else if(CLIENT.length() != 16 && RETRY_CLIENT == 4){ //IF the lenght of the user is diferent from 16 and the Retry Client equals then the cashier closes
            Cashier.close();
        } 
        else if(CLIENT.length() != 16){//if the clientlenght is diferent from 16 then the retry client increases in one (+1)
            System.out.println(TRY);
            RETRY_CLIENT ++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your password length condition and the while loop are inverted.

```
...
else{
    System.out.println("Insert NIP");
    System.out.printf(PROMT);
    while(TIMESP < 4){
        PASSWORD = keyboard.nextLine();
        if(PASSWORD.length() != 4) { 
            System.out.println("Not a valid NIP");
            System.out.println("Please insert a valid NIP");
            TIMESP ++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (TIMESP == 3) {
        Cashier.close();
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP also wants a password with a minimum length of 4, not *"anything but not exactly length() == 4"*.

Comment: True, there's a few things that could be addressed. This just covers the 4 invalid attempts.